# JSON file loaded as one row, one column using pandas read_json; expecting a full dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I was provided with a JSON file which looks something like below when opened with Atom:

```
["[{\"column1\":value1,\"column2\":value2,\"column3\":value3 ...
```

I tried loading it in Jupyter with pandas read_json as such:

```
data = pd.read_json('filename.json', orient = 'records')
```

And when I print `data.head()`, it shows the result below:
[screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTl45.png)

I have also tried the following:

```
import json
with open('filename.json', 'r') as file:
   data = json.load(file)
```

When I check with `type(data)` I see that it is a `list`. When I check with `data[0][1]`, it returns me `{` i.e. it seems that the characters in the file has been loaded as a single element in the list?

Just wondering if I am missing anything? I am expecting the JSON file to be loaded as a dataframe so that I can analyze the data inside. Appreciate any guidance and advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are `value1`, `value2` strings that are not escaped?

Comment: Hmmm, there are 33 columns (or keys) and each column will have different datatype for its value. So `value1` could be int, while `value2` may be string. When I check the strings values, it seems to have been escaped. For example, I can see this in Atom: \"column5\":\"value5\", ...

Comment: And in your file is a list of lists of objects? So each row should represent one list?

Comment: Hmm..I am actually not sure. How can I check that to confirm? It seems to me when I open up the JSON file with Atom, it is just one very long row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think as `head()` only shows one entry that the outer brackets are not needed. I would try to read your file as a string and change the string to something that `pd.read_json()` can parse. I assume that your file contains data in a form like this:

```
["[{\"column1\":2,\"column2\":\"value2\",\"column3\":4}, {\"column1\":4,\"column2\":\"value2\",\"column3\":8}]"]
```

Now, I would read it and remove trailing `\n` if they exist and correct the automatic escaping of the `read()` method. Then I remove `["` and `"]` from the string with this code:

```
with open('input.json', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().rstrip()

cleaned_string = data.replace('\\', '')[2:-2]
```

The result is now a valid json string that looks like this:

```
'[{"column1":2,"column2":"value2","column3":4}, {"column1":4,"column2":"value2","column3":8}]'
```

This string can now be easily read by pandas with this line:

```
pd.read_json(cleaned_string, orient = 'records')
```

Output:

```
    column1 column2 column3
0   2   value2  4
1   4   value2  8
```

The specifics (e.g. the indices to remove unused characters) could be different for your string as I do not know your input. However, I think this approach allows you to read your data.

Comment: Thank you so much JANO! Your solution is exactly what solves my problem. I appreciate your time and patience!

Comment: Glad I could help!